# Почему не запускается приложение в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qapplication

После запуска кода не появляется приложение, но выводится это:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Редактор кода")
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 350, 200)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

def application():
    app = QApplication
    window = Window()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application()
```

Comment: Не знаю как в PyQt5, но в PySide6 `app.exec_()` объявлена как `depricated`, следует использовать просто `app.exec()` без подчеркивания.

Comment: Всегда запускайте ваши приложение в CMD/консоли/терминале и вы получите реальную ошибку. Ошибка `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный номер ошибки, возникает при бесконечной рекурсии. (Переполнение стека).

В данном случае отладчик показывает что ошибка бросается откуда-то из недр qt, при создании первого же окна.

На самом деле, вы забыли инициализировать приложение (QApplication) до создания первого окна. Строка `app = QApplication` - не создает объект класса QApplication, а присваивает переменной app класс в качестве значения, а нужно создать экземпляр класса. Исправление:

```
def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает